# Tracking sales data separate from account information

Tags: bestpractice, data-model

Sales data should be tracked somewhere separate from the Account Information, with Sales data only available to designated Users.  What are solutions you would suggest for accomplishing this?

Comment: Is this some kinda homework assignment?

Comment: @Prady no the way i asked do sound like that,but the problem here is first time i am taking part during designing phase of a project..

Comment: okies... but these exact set of questions were asked by couple of other people to me outside of SE and had the exact same wordings

Comment: Sravan, if you're struggling with these questions, are you sure you're ready to be doing a solution design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the sales data in its own sobject and associate it with the account via a lookup field on the sales data record.  Then I would grant access to that sobject via a permission set that is applied to designated user records.